# Sending array using jquery post

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have a php page which contains an array of input boxes arranged in a Table. Each row contains information regarding each member of the fund. and different columns pertains to the money paid by them under different heads. I want to use this for updating the mysql table which contains members' accounts. How to make an array of this and send a post request using jquery?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function () {

        //create an array of values in each row
        jQuery.post("scripts/update.php", {

            //send array to the script
        }, function (data) {

            alert(data);
        });
    }
});



</script>

</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="">
<table><tr><th>Mem No.</th><th>Subcription</th><th>Loan</th><th>Interest</th></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="text" id="memberno1"  value="1001"/></td><td><input type="text" id="sub1" /></td><td><input type="text" id="loan1"/></td><td> <input type="text" id="int1" /></td></tr>

<tr><td>
<input type="text" id="memberno2"value="1002" /></td><td><input type="text" id="sub2" /></td><td><input type="text" id="loan2"/></td><td> <input type="text" id="int2" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="text" id="memberno3" value="1003"/></td><td><input type="text" id="sub3" /></td><td><input type="text" id="loan3"/></td><td> <input type="text" id="int3" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="text" id="memberno4" value="1004"/></td><td><input type="text" id="sub4" /></td><td><input type="text" id="loan4"/></td><td> <input type="text" id="int4" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="text" id="memberno5" value="1005"/></td><td><input type="text" id="sub5" /></td><td><input type="text" id="loan5"/></td><td> <input type="text" id="int5" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="text" id="memberno6" value="1006"/></td><td><input type="text" id="sub6" /></td><td><input type="text" id="loan6"/></td><td> <input type="text" id="int6" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="text" id="memberno7" value="1007"/></td><td><input type="text" id="sub7" /></td><td><input type="text" id="loan7"/></td><td> <input type="text" id="int7" /></td></tr></table>
<input type="submit" valueue="Save" id="submit"/>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Forms submit their data in name/value pairs. Each of your controls needs a name - replace the id= with name=. If you want to use arrays to  pass the data then use name='int[]' as php will process these are arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, iterate over all the table rows and for each iterate over all input fields:

```
var arr = $('#form1 tr:gt(0)').map(function() {
    return [$('input', this).map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get()];
}).get();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/netayaga/1/edit)

One caveat is that you have to rely on the order of each field.

Comment: I checked demo and not getting output. I tried the same in my script, But the returned array was a comma separated values of all the input boxes, not a multi dimensional array

Comment: @mansoondreamz I think you ran it with the first version of my answer, because the code as it's written above yields a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: I used the above code without any modification. See this http://jsbin.com/netayaga/2/edit If I enter some values, it is not taking

Comment: OK I got it and will post back the result

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an empty `array` and push every input in there then use it to your POST. Something like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function () {

        var inputArray = [];

        $('#form').find('input[type=text]').each(function() {
            // get the value or something from each input

            inputArray.push($(this).val());
        })

        //create an array of values in each row
        jQuery.post("scripts/update.php", {
            'inputs' : inputArray //send array to the script
        }, function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    }
});
```

You should get `inputs` as an array with values from your input texts. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery.post( url, data, callback)

By using serialize, you can send the whole form automatically.

```
   jQuery.post("scripts/update.php", 
              $("form#form1").serialize(), 
              function (data) {
                 alert(data);
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'ajax-post-url.php',
 type: 'POST', // or GET method
 dataType: 'json',
 data: $('.form').serialize(), // all data
 success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
 }
});
```

or

```
$.post('ajax-post-url.php', $('.form').serialize(), function(response) {
 console.log(response);
});
```